# Do I need to cast enums to their numerical counterpart?

Tags: c#, enums, byte

I have set up a `enum` like this:

```
public enum ServerCommands:byte {
    New = 0,
    Join = 1,
}
```

And I want to use it like this:

```
byte command = buffer[0];

if (command == ServerCommands.Join) // Error: Operator == cannot be operands of type 'byte' and 'ServerCommands'.
```

Why is this not possible to do and how can I make it work? They are both of type `byte`.

Comment: Error message isn't clear? By the way http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: Yea im sorry about the title didnt know what to title

Comment: `ServerCommands` is not of type `byte`, it's an `Enum` underlying type is `byte`. Just cast `ServerCommands.Join` to byte and done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to cast from `byte` to `ServerCommands`! This is not done automatically. Assinging numbers to enum values is just for clarity when casting `enum` to `int` or other permitted numeric types.

---

Assigning numeric values to enum values does not change their type to the numeric type! You can cast any enum value to an `int`, as all enums (if not declared otherwise) can be cast to `int`, the first enum value having `int` value `0`.

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    First,
    Second
}
```

is equal to

```
public enum MyEnum : int
{
    First = 0,
    Second
}
```

The feature of numbering enum values is required if the number is not linear, as in:

```
public enum ErrorCodes: int
{
    Success = 0,
    FileNotFound = 1,
    MissingRights = 5,
    WhatTheHeck = 18
}
```

Comment: Thats actually kinda cheap by c#

Comment: That may be, but that's the way it is :-) Actually it is pretty logical - C# is typesafe.

Comment: Yea if you forget what type the enum is :P

Comment: No. An `enum` does not have a numeric datatype! `enum` *is* a data type. There is no direct conversion between numbers and enums.

Comment: hmm but why is it possible to set the type to it? : (type) ?

Comment: To tell it that it *can* be cast to that numeric type. By default you can *cast* an enum to `int`, but unlike in other languages the enum values are not of type `int`, but of type `ServerCommands`. Actually, this feature is not meant to define the *type*, but to define the values the enum values are assigned to if not ordered "normally". I will change my answer.

Comment: @Arbitur: this is done if you want to use an explicit encoding. For instance so you can define bitwise or (`|`), etc. operators.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: I think if you use flags, `First` should be equal to `1`, second to `2`, etc. And you can do this automatically with the `[Flags]` attribute.

Comment: @CommuSoft ... which you could do directly with enum values, too ([Flags] attribute), but still your point is valid.

Comment: @CommuSoft I know. But what if you want to store the flags in a database, for example? You'd have to restore those. Also, my sample wasn't meant to look "flag like" - I'll modify again.

Comment: Still: Assigning numeric values to enum values doesn't make then numeric, which is by design for type safety.

Answer (score 2):

You better state conversions explicitly:

```
if (command == (byte) ServerCommands.Join)
```

or even better:

```
if ((ServerCommands) command == ServerCommands.Join) //always convert to the more restrictive type.
```

This is a precaution to prevent one from comparing values without knowing that the objects are from a different type.

Equality means that **both** objects have the same type. This is not the case. `ServerCommands` *extend* from byte. Thus a byte is not per se a valid `ServerCommands` object...

Furthermore the `: byte` is more used as an *explicit encoding*. Having the same binary encoding does not imply two objects are the same. For instance `14.25f` and `0x41640000` are binary the same...

Comment: Do I really have to do that??

Comment: What's the problem. It prevents one from performing checks without reasoning about the implications.

Comment: @Arbitur: It's not because two objects share the same encoding, that the objects are necessarily equal. For instance `14.25f` is binary equal to `0x41640000`, but not in value...

Comment: @Arbitur yes and it'll save you from errors like `if (cmbGender.SelectedIndex == PaymentMethod.CreditCard)` (OK it's little bit too fictional but you understand what I mean).

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to cast your enum:

```
if (command == (byte)ServerCommands.Join)
```